# Why won't the strings command stop?

Tags: linux, shell, string

The `strings` command behaves weirdly, apparently it doesn't stop writing to a file even if drive run out of space. Or perhaps I'm missing something?

I run the following:

```
# strings /dev/urandom > random.txt
```

this was keep running and didn't stop even after filling the disk (a regular usb flash).

then to be quicker I created a ramdisk and tried again the same command. it also didn't stop.

I understand that `urandom` isn't a regular file and also `strings`'s output is redirected, however in both cases above, the `cat` command reported the error when there was no more space.

```
# cat /dev/urandom > random.txt
cat: write error: No space left on device
```

1. Is this normal behavior of strings? If so, why?
2. Where is the data written after there's no more space left?

Comment: What was the indication that your first command had actually filled up the disk?

Comment: @Kusalananda It was reported by df. I was monitoring it from another virtual terminal using watch df -h

Comment: @Kusalananda: you can test this easily with `strace strings /dev/urandom > /dev/full`

Comment: @PeterCordes If I was on a Linux system, yes. It is clear from the accepted answer that `strings` in GNU binutils does not check the return value of `putchar()` properly.

Comment: @Kusalananda what implementation of `strings(1)` are you using?

Comment: Simpler testcase for those who don't run linux and/or want to fill up their disk with garbage: `(trap '' PIPE; strings /bin/sh && echo >&2 BUG) | true`

Comment: @mosvy OpenBSD uses that same `strings` implementation from GNU binutils. I was referring to the `strace` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda OK, because the "BSD toolchain" replacement of strings(1) doesn't check for the return value of putchar() [either](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/strings/strings.c#l396)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If GNU `cat` can't write out what it read, [it will exit with an error](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c#L187):

```c
/* Write this block out.  */

{
  /* The following is ok, since we know that 0 < n_read.  */
  size_t n = n_read;
  if (full_write (STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n)
    die (EXIT_FAILURE, errno, _("write error"));
}
```

GNU `strings`, on the other hand, [doesn't care](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/strings.c;h=648bdc081271b2c9c7505066a5622b009cd58437;hb=HEAD#l684) whether it managed to write successfully:

```c
while (1)
  {
    c = get_char (stream, &address, &magiccount, &magic);
    if (c == EOF)
      break;
    if (! STRING_ISGRAPHIC (c))
      {
        unget_part_char (c, &address, &magiccount, &magic);
        break;
      }
    putchar (c);
  }
```

So all those writes fail, but `strings` continues merrily along, until it reaches end of input, which will be never.

```c
$ strace -e write strings /dev/urandom > foo/bar
write(1, "7[\\Z\n]juKw\nl [1\nTc9g\n0&}x(x\n/y^7"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "\nXaki%\ndHB0\n?5:Q\n6bX-\np!E[\n'&=7\n"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "%M6s\n=4C.%\n&7)n\nQ_%J\ncT+\";\nK*<%\n"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "&d<\nj~g0\nm]=o\na=^0\n%s]2W\nM7C%\nUK"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "~\nd3qQ\n^^u1#\na#5\\\n^=\t\"b\n*91_\n ]o"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "L\n6QO1x\na,yE\nk>\",@Z\nyM.ur\n~z\tF\nr"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "\n61]R\nyg9C\nfLVu\n<Ez:\n.tV-c\nw_'>e"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "\nCj)a\nT]X:uA\n_KH\"B\nRfQ4G\n3re\t\n&s"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "j\nk7@%\n9E?^N\nJ#8V\n*]i,\nXDxh?\nr_1"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "ia\tI\nQ)Zw\nnV0J\nE3-W \n@0-N2v\nK{15"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
write(1, "\nZ~*g\n)FQn\nUY:G\ndRbN\nn..F\nvF{,\n+"..., 4096) = -1 ENOSPC (No space left on device)
...
```

Comment: Nice analysis. I'd say that should be considered a bug in `strings`.

Comment: Anyone planning to report the bug?